# How to connect to Access Database via Data Sources (ODBC) using a mapped network drive?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, dsn

I need to make a connection to an Access Database. In order to do that I created a System DSN. I had success making that connection using local files.

However, the database must be at a remote server and I mapped a network drive so I can access the database files. Mapping the drive and using the remote files, an error arises when I try to access the database:

"**[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.**
"

If I use the database files in the local machine, the error doesn't appear. But accessing the file from the network drive, the exception is throw. Do you know why it happens?

Thanks....

Comment: Are you using a mapped drive or UNC paths?

Comment: Doesn't the second paragraph say that he's using a mapped drive?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the files using the UNC path (i.e., what the drive is mapped to)?

Comment: Is the workgroup file being explicitly called somewhere, such as in the shortcut you're using? Or is it possible the default workgroup file on the PC is set to a mapped drive that is no longer defined?

Comment: I tried also using UNC paths but the error continues.

The file is not being in use... I have full control of it.

I believe that is some Authentication issue because the application is running under the SYSTEM user context... I have been reading some posts with the same problem but using IIS context and the problem is related to Kerberos configurations.

Comment: Using a connection string or creating and DSN connection, the error is the same.... :(

Comment: Are you specifying a workgroup file?

Comment: Are you specifying the right workgroup file? Is it accessible via the path you've provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The application invoking my code is a windows service that is running under the SYSTEM account. This account doesn't have permissions to access files outside the server.

A system administrator will create a special account and I need to use it as the service log on account.

Answer (score 0):

This will sound odd, but add your AD domain to your Trusted Sites in your internet options.

So if your computer is a member of `ad.mycompany.com`, use that.

I had something similar happen with two people trying to open up the same MDB on a network drive.